# WPF and D3DImage view update not working

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, interop, d3dimage

I am having a WPF application where in I have a native directx r endering engine at the backend and a WPF View as the front end. The directx rendering engine returns a WPF surface which I update on every render call.

I have linked the two via the D3DImage as shown below under my user control:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Background>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding D3DRenderImage}" />
   </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

At the beginning of each render call, I get a call back from the native to the managed side where in I lock the image, and on a similar call back at the end of a render call I get a rendering finished callback where I invalidate the image and unlock it.

On any view manipulation operation, I inform the underlying rendering engine about the same, and it starts the rendering the sequence. All of this happens perfectly. The problem is that my background image is not refreshed instantaneously. It get refreshed if I change the focus to some other application window and come back to my application window.

Here is the weird part, If I add a progress bar to my user control, the view is updated perfectly? Any idea on what could be going on behind the scenes?

**P.S.**  I am new to WPF and thus I might not have been be able to frame the problem correctly. Sorry about that :-(

Comment: Have you tried to call D3DImage.AddDirtyRect each time you need to redraw?